# .NET XML web service returned collection as array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am working with an XML web service using VB.NET, created using VS 2010. One of my web methods returns a collection(type that inherits from list) of custom objects. It's a simple return statement, it is my understanding that .NET handles most of the tricky protocol stuff as well as serializing/unserialzing of objects.

The issue is in my consuming application when I get the the return value of the web method that returns a custom collection I get an array of the custom objects. Is this normal behavior? It will be easy enough for me to take that array and insert  it into a custom collection object but if I could I would like to skip this step. Googling hasn't returned anything that I found useful. Could anyone tell me if this is typical behavior? Thanks much!

Comment: What particular flavor of web-services are you setting up?  Are you able to use [data contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx)?

Comment: I am using an XML web service project using .NET version 3.5.

Comment: Classes implementing IEnumerable or ICollection (which your will, inheriting from List) serialize to arrays by default. Try seeing if your application will observe and use data contract attributes, to set explicit serialization rules. Otherwise, you can set explicit serialization handlers for your class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using WCF, try adding `CollectionDataContractAttribute` to your custom collection, as per **Customizing Collection Types** section of [Collection Types in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx).

In the case you are using your service by setting up a Service Reference in the consuming application, then an even easier method would be to right-click the service name, select Configure Service Reference..., and about 1/3rd the way down of the dialog that pops up there will be a dropdown with "Collection type:" label.  Default is to use `System.Array`, but here you can easily change it to use whichever collection type you prefer.